# How can I make a Windows 7 computer appear to be Linux to remote OS detectors

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a Windows 7 computer that I'd like to spoof as Linux on my network. By that, I mean that anyone on the network who runs nmap or a [System Properties scan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781551%28WS.10%29.aspx) would think that my computer (running W7) was a Linux computer. The spoof would only need to hold up to cursory inspection such as direct TCP or UDP traffic, not necessarily packet inspection between my computer and one not on the network. I know that using IPtables on Linux makes it possible to do the opposite of this... but I'm not entirely familiar with the set of tools available in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least one program that can easily change the OS fingerprint for Windows systems so they look like something else.

[OSfuscate](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/osfuscate-change-your-windows-os-tcp-ip-fingerprint-to-confuse-p0f-networkminer-ettercap-nmap-and-other-os-detection-tools)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'll probably read up a bit more on OSfuscate to determine if I can perform this same tweak without the program itself.